# STUN Authentication and DTLS Support in Browsers

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, stun, coturn

I am setting up a webRTC environment with janus and coturn.
Even though STUN is a very lightweight protocol I would like to authenticate it if possible, and [according to the STUN specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389#section-10) that is the case.

Coturn also supports authentication for both STUN and TURN, I am using it with the `--use-auth-secret` and `--secure-stun` flags.

I can verify that the authentication works perfectly using the `username` and `credential` flags for the TURN configuration in `iceServers`, but for STUN it just won't do anything.

It was hard enough to get reliable information about the ICE exchange because I cannot find useful information in `chrome://webrtc-internals` and `onicestatechange` etc. but with WireShark I was able to inspect the STUN requests themselves and it turns out that Chrome completely ignores the `username` and `credential` fields for `stun:...` servers.

**EDIT**: I realized now that this is documented on MDN.

It also seems like Chrome doesn't support the DTLS-secured `stuns:...` protocol and `turns:...` only as TLS/via TCP transports.

Are there plans to support these features? Where can I find them or why not? The supported features (only stun auth...) seem very arbitrary to me.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to ask the Chrome developers themselves but the reason behind the `arbitrarily supported features` is that what you're looking for is written in an entirely different RFC whereas auth was in the original STUN RFC.

There's very little benefit to a DTLS STUN and TURN so I can't see them prioritizing it very high.